# Reordering Foundation XY grid cells on small devices

Tags: css, flexbox, leaflet, zurb-foundation

I'm just getting started using the Zurb Foundation 6.4.3 [XY Grid](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html). I'm having some trouble conceptualizing how I would do the following:

On **large screens**, my site should look like this:

[image]

On **small screens** I'd like Panel B to come first, and have a fixed height of 300px:

[image]

I have a Codepen of all this here: https://codepen.io/rbrtmrtn/pen/vWYKQP

Right now there are two issues with how this appears on small screens:

1. I'm not sure how to make Panel B appear above Panel A when that `grid-x` gets collapsed.
2. Panel B is a [web map](http://leafletjs.com/) which requires a fixed height or some kind of autosizing (like Flexbox `grow`) in order to work. When I resize the site and collapse the `grid-x` the map disappears, probably because Foundation is trying to fit the cell to its content and there is none (the map behaves more like a floated element).

Would appreciate any help sorting this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coworker steered me in the right direction -- the answer was to use [source ordering](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flexbox-utilities.html#source-ordering), which allows you to specify the order in which elements appear on different screen sizes.